# Only one virtual host can reach the gateway at a time?

Tags: networking, vmware-esxi

I've installed vSphere 6.0 and gotten one host up and running. But it seems that no matter what I do, only one host can reach the gateway at one time. Any other hosts brought up can ping other virtual hosts and the ESXi hardware, but can't get any further than that. And the same is true from the outside: I can reach ESXi and one host from outside that subnet, but any others are unreachable.

I've verified that each host is configured properly and identically, and that they have different MAC addresses, and even gone as far as to clone a VM that had network access, with no success.

The upstream network hardware isn't under my control, but they swear there isn't anything that should be causing this behavior.

This is my first time in this kind of environment, so I'm also a little lost in terms of how to troubleshoot. I can provide more information as needed.

---

**Edit:** This is on an HP ProLiant DL380p Gen8. It has a Broadcom NetXtreme BCM5719, 1 Gbit full duplex. The guests are CentOS 7 x64, with vmxnet3 adapters (but Intel E1000 adapters exhibit the same behavior).

Comment: Do you use any vlans to segregate your network? Are your virtual machines on the same port group?

Comment: No, we're not using any vlans. All the virtual machines are on the same port group.

Comment: What if you change the IP address of the working server. Do you still have connection?

Comment: Yes, I changed its IP address, verified it changed, and still had connectivity.

Comment: Have you done ANY training whatsoever or read any documentation about virtual networking before coming here?

Comment: @Chopper3 A little; I'm just a student worker at my college. But nothing I've been able to find has been helpful.

Comment: "Server Fault is for questions about managing information technology systems in a business environment." - we're a site for professional sysadmins sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. It was an upstream network configuration issue, some kind of MAC filtering or something.

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like either you have some mismatched speeds or configuration.

1. Make sure your hardware NIC and software NIC are the same speeds.
2. If you have a port channel configured, drop it down to a single link and test if that's the issue. (literally unplug all but 1 cable.)
3. Try Disabling [netQ](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2035701)

In the future, please include all hardware information, Host, NIC, speeds, switches involved, and then the guest OS and virtual NIC used.

Comment: They are the same speed. We aren't using port channel, there is normally only one link. Disabling netqueue didn't help either. I have also added more information to the question.

Comment: Can the servers see each other? ICMP or TCP, what's your broadcast domain?  can you give us your IPs?